The breakpoint will not currently be hit no executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line
I honestly am at a loss here, I have never experience debugger behavior like this before and I don't believe I am experience enough to understand the solutions I have found in other questions.
Basically, I have similar code that works fine in another area of my program but here it is essentially skipping the if statements giving the warning listed in the title.
I thought it might be event.joyStickButton.button that was causing it, but it acts the same when I just put it as button in the second if statement. Additionally, it is fine in the following print statement. What is going on here?


Where are you trying to put the breakpoint?

Add a tag for the debugger you're using.

If an if block has an empty body, and the condition has no side effects, the compiler may remove it entirely.

@Barmar, I am trying to put one on line 39. In it's current state it skips the breakpoint and code entirely even though the statement is true (button is 8).

Aside: Why aren't you using the button variable there?

@Barmar I do not even know what the debugger I am using is. I am just using Visual Studio 2022. And I have tried it with the button variable in the if conditional as well but the same breakpoint behavior.

If you're using an IDE, that's the debugger.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

The statement cursorPosition != cursorPosition; doesn't do anything, so that code has been removed, so the if statement was removed as well.

The comment // they hit select, move cursor is wrong, that statement doesn't move anything.

Make sure you disable optimization when you're debugging.

@Barmar good catch, that was it. I meant to write "cursorPosition = !cursorPosition;" However, the breakpoint behavior is still the same on the corrected line? The code is running as expected now but I still can't stop at that breakpoint?

That's a weird way to move the cursor. It's not a boolean.

What happens if you single-step instead of setting a breakpoint?

For this issue, i have the following suggestions to troubleshoot:
1.Navigate to Tools=>Options=>Debugging=>General and check Suppress JIT optimization on module load.
2.Right click project node and select Properties->C/C++->Optimization then set Optimization to  "Disabled (/Od)".
3.I have found this old ticket, you can check this option Check for consistent line endings on load by going to Tools > Options > Environment > Documents and unselect "Check for consistent line endings on load.

That seemed to fix this. Although I do not know why it worked or what the problem even was initially.
